# Is it possible to distinguish the calls based on data type in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've two action methods one with parameter as integer and other as parameter as string. Is there any way to make these work?

Both methods have id as parameter but different data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by providing datatype for the parameters passed to the method as shown below

```
    [HttpGet, Route("SomeMethod/{id}")]
    public string SomeMethod(string Id)
    {
        return "string";
    }

    [HttpGet, Route("SomeMethod/{id:int}")]
    public string SomeMethod(int Id)
    {
        return "int";
    }
```

The second method had {id:int} component in the route that tells it that the id parameter has to be of datatype int to match this method. The caveat here is that you cannot pass strings that could be passed into int. For eg. if you wish to pass string Id "1", it will bind to the int method instead of the string  method.

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx) is some more info on attribute routing in MVC

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[ActionName("smt")]`

```
            public ActionResult Add(int id)
            {
                return View();
            }

            [ActionName("another")]
            public ActionResult Add(string id)
            {
                return View("index");
            }
```